# Is it easier to rewrite a pyomo model into a Docplex or a Gurobi model?

Tags: python, pyomo, gurobi, docplex, qiskit

I've got an optimization problem written in pyomo that I want to translate to Qiskit. The only issue is that Qiskit has the ability to take in Docplex or Gurobi models. My question is this:
Is it easier to rewrite a pyomo model into a Docplex or a Gurobi model?

Comment: Did you find an answer in the end, @Ahmad Bennakhi?

Comment: @LarsSchellhas nope, but I moved on from the topic since the number of qubits needed to represent my problems just don't scale well.

Comment: Fair. The number of qubits currently definitely is a very limiting constraint for optimisation problems.